# send argument to command prompt of a remote PC

Tags: python, windows, cmd, remote-access

I am looking for a way to open command prompt of remote PC by using Python. In this process I came only upto  open a command prompt from Python and other code is connecting to a windows remote PC but how to combine these two  and opening the command prompt of remote PC  ?

Simply, I want to send some arguments/commands to remote PC command prompt.

Thank you.

Comment: perhaps try setting up an ssh server?

Comment: Yeah... I'm a bit suspicious of this post and OP's intentions. Why do you want to basically take control of a remote host?

Comment: @AlexThornton No I am not with such thoughts. Ok I have to manage 5 IIS servers( Remote) , I need to get sitelist and updated list of bindings  on time basis. So If I have a  script  I can do that easily. Surely there is no any negative usage or purpose.

Comment: @JoranBeasley can I send arguments to remote PC command prompt using SSH ?

Comment: @shekhar The whole idea of SSH is that you set up a **secure shell** through which you can send information to a remote host. It is possible to do this through Python.

Comment: @shekhar you would need to download ssh software onto the remote PC's and then connect to the ssh service running on them through py-ssh (or whatever its called) ... also I dont see any reason to suspect malicious intent with this question ... you just need to do a little more research

Comment: I mean I want it in Python because I am learning it. I love it if it is with python. Thank you @AlexThornton

Comment: I'm confused! Do you want to open a command prompt or just execute programs remotely? If the latter, windows allows remote program execution via several mechanisms, including [WMI](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install SSH on the remote PC's. You test the connection and make sure you are able to login. Google can help if you've not setup ssh before.

Then you can create a python script locally to execute commands over the ssh connection.

You'll probably want to look at either

Fabric -> http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/

or

Paramiko -> http://www.paramiko.org/

Which will be able to run your commands.